# How do I get Delphi record with TArray in it, of same record type, to clone whole array to a new instance?

Tags: delphi

With this it's possible to create deep branching structures of unspecified 'depth'

```
TGItem = record
  NameShort:            String;
  NameLong:             String;
  Formula:              String;
  Components:           TArray<TGItem>;
  procedure Init;
end;

var 
 A,B: TGItem;

 B := A;
```

The .Components in both A and B point to same array, but I want to duplicate the array. How do I do that?

Version 10.4

Edit/Current progress:

```
class operator Assign(var Dest: TGItem; const [ref] Src: TGItem);
```

and

```
class operator TGItem.Assign(var Dest: TGItem; const [ref] Src:TGItem);
begin
  // What to put here?
end;
```

Comment: There are several ways to copy an object. In short, a copy constructor, a clone method, or a TPersistent with assign method. Show us some attempt with any of those and if you still have problems, we may then help you with the specific question.

Comment: @PA. TGItem is not an object.

Comment: ooops right my mistake

Answer (score 1):

```
function TGItem.Clone: TGItem;
begin
  Result.Init;    
  Result.NameShort        := Self.NameShort;
  Result.NameLong         := Self.NameLong;
  Result.Formula          := Self.Formula;
  Setlength(Result.Components, Length(Self.Components));
    
  var I: Integer;
  for I := 0 to Length(Result.Components)-1 do
  begin
    Result.Components[I] := Self.Components[I].Clone;
  end;    
end;
```

Seems to work, instead of `B := A` I use `B := A.Clone` and it does a recursive copy and creates a new cloned branching structure (instead of pointing to the old structure).

Comment: I'd write `var I: Integer; for I := 0 to Length(Result.Components)-1 do` as `for var i := 0 to High(Result.Components) do`

Comment: And I'd write it as _for var i := LOW(Result.Components) to HIGH(Result.Components) do_ - I fyou use HIGH, then use LOW as well...

Comment: Alternatively: `var I: Integer = 0; for var comp in Self.Components do begin Result.Components[I] := comp.Clone; Inc(I); end;`

Comment: You can also use: `System.Generics.Collections.TArray.Copy`